# win 10 to win 7 - double redirection

Tags: windows, virtualbox, port-forwarding

i have a win7 with Vbox installed. i use putty to connect the VM from the host using the port redirection feature included in VBox settings.

Now i want to connect from the same network but from another computer (W10).
i turn on port redirecion in the W7 with "PassPort" program:

source_ip: host_ip:22 - - -  dest_ip: 127.0.0.1:22 (that have another redireccion to the Vbox machine done via port redirection in Vbox settings)

but putty can`t connect from the W10.

Yes, i know i can do it changing the VM from NAT to bridged, but anyway i want to know how to do it...

i missed something?...return path?....any config in putty --> tunnels?

regards

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, no port forwarding is needed on Win 7. Simply connect from the Win 10 machine using the IP address of the Win 7 machine as a destination. The port forwarding in vbox should handle that. Make sure there are no firewall rules on Win 7 or the VM that would block the connection.

Comment: thanks, but the config in VBox is doing with [127.0.0.1:22 --> VBox_IP:22], so, if i connect from another IP distinct from 127.0.0.1, i need another redirection, isn`t?

Comment: Why are you specifying 127.0.0.1 in your port forwarding rules? You don’t have to do that. You can leave it blank.

Comment: You are completely right, leaving it blank means any ip....of course :-)....Case close